# rxjs: Can an Observable implementation invoke onNext on the same thread of execution?

Tags: reactive-programming, rxjs

In ReactiveX an Observable might invoke
the following methods

- onNext
- onError
- onCompleted

according to a very clear contract http://reactivex.io/documentation/contract.html

I am writing the code for the Observable and I have realized that under certain circumstances I might invoke onNext within the same thread of execution.
Is that a mistake ?

For example, if I have code like this:

```
// call onNext twice on the same thread execution.
o.onNext(event1);
o.onNext(event2);
```

Should I rewrite it like this:

```
// call onNext and then schedule the next call via setTimeout
o.onNext(event1);
setTimeout(function() { o.onNext(event2); },0);
```

= = = = = = = =

**Clarification:** **why am I asking ?**
In a browser, let's imagine the observer wants to update an HTML element with the content of onNext then if it is called serially that code would not work.

```
function onNext() {
   count++;
   htmlElement.innerHTML = 'count:'+count; // <-- this will work only if onNext is invoked on different thread of executions.
}
```

Comment: No, it's not a mistake and there's no need to re-write it. The contract states that the `onNext` calls must happen serially, which they do in your example.

Comment: @cartant where does the contract state that it must happen serially ?

Comment: In "The Contract Governing Notifications" section: "Observables must issue notifications to observers serially (not in parallel)". I note that your question includes JavaScript. Being single-threaded, it's not possible to issue parallel `onNext` calls, so it's a non-issue for that language.

Comment: @cartant thanks for your help; note that  javascript is single-threaded, but you can still call onEvent on a different thread of execution or decide not to.